# Objective-C ASCII to plain text

Tags: objective-c, ascii

I am trying to get the ASCII numbers I load from a file to convert into plain text.  I've looked at NSASCIIStringEncoding, but when I run it it just returns what I inputted.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSData *asciiData = [[myWords objectAtIndex:d] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Here's an example:

ASCII string:  117 32 119 97

Expected output:  u wa?

Comment: What do you expect as output as ASCII numbers are plain text

Comment: well I was expecting the text that those numbers represent, but it didn't happen, and I couldn't find the answer, so I'm asking here

Comment: You'll want to parse each sequence-of-digits as a number, and then output that sequence-of-numbers as a string.

Comment: I have the parsing done already, what do you mean "output as a string"??

Comment: ASCII == plain text, I guess you are not after ASCII ...

Comment: Please post a sample of your input and your expected output. Your question is very unclear as to what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments on your question, it sounds like your input file looks something like this:

```
65 66 67
```

That is technically eight ASCII characters: the character for the digit '6', the character for the digit '5', the character for a space ' ', etc.

If you want to read those as numbers, and then output the ASCII characters they represent, you should read the file using NSString's initWithContentsOfFile:, then use NSScanner to convert those character sequences into numbers. Then, you can output those numbers directly to a file, casting them as type `char`, and the resulting file will be:

```
ABC
```

You don't actually need to declare that the numbers are ASCII when you output the file; ASCII is a system for *interpreting* a sequence of numbers as text. It's an ASCII file by virtue of the fact that it happens to look OK when you open it with a text editor.